# How to distribute layers across multiple devices in tensorflow?

Tags: parallel-processing, tensorflow, distributed

How can I distribute computation(compute-gradient,apply-gradient) across multiple devices to achieve model parallelism?

I've managed to distribute vars by setting `minimize(colocate_gradients_with_ops=True)` but I'm not sure that it is enough to get model parallelism correctly.

Comment: you can use `with tf.device(<somedevice>)` to assign ops to different devices

Comment: Yes. I already have tf.device scopes for ops(forward pass) but optimizers ops(gradients/back-props) couldn't be assigned to multiple devices because of this op is atomic.

https://github.com/nakosung/tensorflow-wavenet/blob/model_parallel_2/train.py
https://github.com/nakosung/tensorflow-wavenet/blob/model_parallel_2/wavenet/model.py#L120

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the right way to do model parallelism in tensorflow?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40216948/what-is-the-right-way-to-do-model-parallelism-in-tensorflow)